# Wordpress - Woocommerce, remove pagination from before shop loop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, pagination

With woocommerce on the archive pages, there is a before shop loop that includes pagination.

The pagination is also included after the shop loop so I want to remove it from the top of the page and leave it at the bottom.

This is the archive page code. Removing the before shop loop php code from the top of the page works but breaks the page formatting with the sidebar:

```
<?php
/** * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page which is a post type archive. * * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php * * @author WooThemes * @package WooCommerce/Templates * @version 2.0.0 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>

    <?php echo mad_title(array(
        'title' => woocommerce_page_title(false)
    )); ?>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' ); ?>

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>

            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );
        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' );
?>
```

If anyone can help me work out how to do this i would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

In the woocommerce config.php the theme developer had added

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', array(&$this, 'woocommerce_pagination'));
```

commenting this out resolved the issue.